# Как получить доступ к методам класса PHP

Tags: php, ооп

есть такая иерархия классов

```
class Test {  }  // главный класс

class User extends Test {
   function foo () {
     return 'func foo';
   } 
 }  

 class Desc extends Test {
   function foo_desc () {
    // здесь нужно вызвать функцию foo из класса User
  }
}
```

Нужно вызвать методы соседнего по родству класса User из класса Desc, как это реализовать?

Comment: Плюс всегда в классах пишите видимость метода (public/private/protected).

Comment: @FoxDev, я в курсе про модификатор видимости, мне нужно получить доступ к методам без явного создания объекта просто через `$this->user`

Answer (score 1):

```
class Test {  }  // главный класс

class User extends Test {
   function foo () {
     return 'func foo';
   } 
 }  

 class Desc extends Test {
   function foo_desc () {
    $u = new User;
    $u->foo();
  }
}
```

Comment: Да это работает, но есть же лучше методы? этот способ я и сам знаю, необходимо реализовать без явного создания объекта класса, например вызывать вот так - `$this->user->foo();`

Comment: @modelfak нет, лучше методов подтянуть чужой функционал, кроме как вызвать его напрямую, нет. Вы просите примерно следующее: сделайте так, чтобы то, что лежит в другом месте, лежало вот в этом, но при этом все равно лежало в другом месте.

Comment: @Etki  добавил свой ответ, посмотрите пожалуйста, и скажите ваше мнение

Answer (score 0):

Вы конечно можете использовать `static` или инициализировать класс как предложил *@jedayka*
но то не являются правильными решениями. Если прислушаться к **Кенту Беку** он в таких ситуациях рекомендует выносить такой метод в родитель

Comment: добавил свой ответ как решение

Answer (score -1):

Вот придумал такое решение, теперь я могу вызывать методы соседнего по родству класса используя - `$this`

```
class TEST { 
 private $classes = array(

    'pages'=>'Pages',
    'users'=>'Users',
    ///..... other

);

public static $objects = array();

 public function __get($name) {

    if(isset(self::$objects[$name]))
    {
        return self::$objects[$name];
    }

    if(!array_key_exists($name, $this->classes))
    {
        return null;
    }
    $class = $this->classes[$name];

    include('classes/'.$class.'.php');


        self::$objects[$name] = new $class();


    return self::$objects[$name];
}


}
```

Теперь внутри любого класса который является наследником TEST я могу вызывать методы любых других его наследников

```
require_once ('classes/TEST.php');

class View extends TEST
{  

   function foo () {
      $this->users->foo();
   }
```

Comment: У вас все упадет при запросе одного класса из двух мест. Но это неважно, потому что у вас проблема XY: вы просите помощи по конкретному решению, но ничего не говорите про проблему.

Comment: @Etki У вас все упадет при запросе одного класса из двух мест - не понял почему?

Comment: потому что два раз заинклюдится файл и класс будет объявлен два раза

Comment: побейте меня если я не прав - Ваше решение подразумевает наличие дублирования

Comment: @Etki `if(isset(self::$objects[$name]))
    {
        return self::$objects[$name];
    }`  вообщето этот метод предотвращает дублирование по идее

Comment: Не заметил статику. Но всего остального это не отменяет.